# Is there any designer-friendly parametric curve, for which $\frac{\text{arclength}}{\text{distance}^2}$ can be calculated?

Tags: integration, arc-length

If I could find an $f(t)$ in the $xy$ plane

where $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{f'_x(t)^2+f'_y(t)^2}}{f_x(t)^2+f_y(t)^2}\, dt$ is known (basically $\displaystyle\frac{\text{arclength}}{\text{distance}^2}$ integrated)

I have tried to use both quadratic and cubic bezier curves, but the results got waay too messy for my realtime application. And I gave up when I found a full explanation of how to find the arc length of bezier curves (I found that it's quite difficult or impossible).

My idea now is that I could design my curve with some other kinds of parameters, so that my calculation will be possible. Does such kind of curve exist??

Comment: What do all the subscripts mean?  Is $f=(f_x, f_y)$?

Comment: That $f(t)$ is a function from $t$ to a point in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Right, so $f$ is a curve in the plane.

Comment: Perhaps curves with simple expressions in polar coordinates will be easier to integrate? Have you tried computing it for circular arcs?

Comment: @preferred_anon good idea, I haven't tried it

Comment: What may be the use of that integral?  In case you translate $f$ a complete different result would appear.

Comment: I'm imagining $\displaystyle\frac{1}{distance^2}$ as an attraction force at point $f(t)$. The integral expresses the attraction force of the whole line, since it's a continuous sum of points.
Because I also multiply with the curve speed (the derivative), the points are weighted so that each little piece of line (length) has the appropriate relative attraction when compared to other points.

For a bezier spline $t$ would run from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Circular arcs. And you can string these together smoothly to get free-form “spline” curves. Look up **biarc curves** to find out more.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biarc

Another option is a so-called **Pythagorean hodograph** curve. These are specifically designed to ensure that the square root term in your integrand simplifies nicely. Rida Farouki wrote an entire book about these creatures:
https://faculty.engineering.ucdavis.edu/farouki/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2013/02/Introduction-to-PH-curves.pdf